# Adding Total Row to Query That Is Dynamic

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my query in google sheets.

```
=QUERY('Payroll Detail '!$A$1:$Z$108, 
 "SELECT A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z WHERE B = '"&A4&"'", 1)
```

It displays employee name in column A. Then from column B - Y it displays monthly payroll data for each employee. This is dynamic in that cell A4 references different departments. So i select department from cell A4 - and then the employees from that department appear with their payroll data by month.

I want to total each column in the query. So basically, have a row that appears after the last employee name and then for each monthly column - sum all of the data. How do i do so?

It can't be static because some departments have more employees than others, so it's not as simple as just adding in a totals row manually.

Tried a number of different workarounds but I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: Hi @Keitth If you've already tried similar workarounds and encountered issues, please provide more details or error messages so that we can further assist you. Additionally, sharing a sample dataset or specific examples would be helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a total row per column, you can use this:

```
=LET(q,put here your query,
VSTACK(q,BYCOL(q,LAMBDA(each,IFERROR(SUM(each),"TOTAL")))))
```

Comment: That worked great!! The totals were added to the bottom of each column. but for some reason the Label "total" does not appear. Just a 0 under the names

Comment: also - is there a way to format the "totals" row so that it appears with a shade of grey on the totals cells?

Comment: =LET(q, QUERY('Payroll Detail '!$A$1:$Z$108, "SELECT A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z WHERE B = '"&A4&"'", 1),
     VStack(q, BYCOL(q, LAMBDA(each, IFERROR(SUM(each), "TOTAL"))))
) this is what the formula looks like. But as previously stated, only a "0" appears. Not the word " TOTAL "